# What happens when I destroy a building?

Tags: banished

I have a boarding house with over 600 food in it, and I don't want to lose it. If I were to destroy the boarding house, would it drop the inventory on the ground or destroy it along with the building?

Comment: they move the inventory before demo, not sure though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a building is marked for demolition, all stored goods inside are scheduled to be moved out before deconstruction. A percentage bar is shown on the building's screen showing how much is left to be moved. Laborers are required to haul the goods somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, just didn't want to risk 600 food, you know :)